# How to find the average of all the values that are output by a while loop?

Tags: while-loop, average

I'm trying to get the average value of all the `r,g,b`s that are output by this while loop. Can any one tell me how?

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <windows.h>
   using namespace std;

  int main()

     {
    int a = 20, c = 20 , loop=0;

            HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, a, c);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
            int r1 = GetRValue(color);
            int g1 = GetGValue(color);
            int b1 = GetBValue(color);

            cout << r1 << " " << g1 << " " << b1 << "\n";


            HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 70, 20);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
            int r2 = GetRValue(color);
            int g2 = GetGValue(color);
            int b2 = GetBValue(color);

            HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 120, 20);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
            int r3 = GetRValue(color);
            int g3 = GetGValue(color);
            int b3 = GetBValue(color);

            HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 170, 20);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
            int r4 = GetRValue(color);
            int g4 = GetGValue(color);
            int b4 = GetBValue(color);
            .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                till r35 g35 b35

            HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
            COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 170, 20);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
            int r35 = GetRValue(color);
            int g35 = GetGValue(color);
            int b35 = GetBValue(color);


          int metaavg = r1 + g1 + b1 + r2 + g2 + b2 + r3 + g3 + b3 +.....
          ...............................................+ r35 + g35 + b35 
                cout << metaavg / 105 ;


system("pause");
   }
```

this is what i want

iam working on "adaptive brightness"

this is a program to calculate white colour of what is being displayed on the screen.........

i dont want to write 600 lines of code.......iam noob.....they dont teach priogramming for doctors here......

everything is done except"wiiting this crap again and again"

is there a better way other than "writing 600 lines of code" or shud i stick with "600 lines of code"

i dont know what.... shadowing..

thank u for the replies....

Comment: You're shadowing r, b, g in the loop which means you're not assigning the values to the variables defined in main().

Comment: Step 1 `a = a + 50, c = c + 25, loop++;` --> `a = a + 50;  c = c + 25;  loop++;`  Step 2 form the summation of the r,g,b values  Step 3 Divide the summations by the loop count, maybe with FP math.

Comment: it loops 35 times .....and et the end of completion of loop there are 35 r,g,b values....i want average of all 105 values......